# How to check all the integers in the list are continuous?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate

I am trying to write a program which will print "YES" if all the numbers in the `list` are continuous and should return "NO" if the numbers are not continuous. By continuous I mean every number in the list should be greater than one from the previous element.

For example:

- It should print "YES" for inputs: `[3, 4, 5]`, `[7, 8, 9]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.. etc
- It should print "NO" for inputs: `[9, 1, 0]`, `[3, 2, 4]`, `[5, 5]`, `[9, 8, 2, 3, 7]`.. etc

I used `enumerate` for this purpose.

Here's my code:

```
    inp=[1,2,3,4,5]
    flag=0
    for index,e in enumerate(inp): 
        if index!=len(inp)-1:    
            if inp[index+1]==inp[index]+1:
                flag=1
    if flag==1:
        print ("YES")
    else:
        print ("NO")
```

The code works fine but i find it redundant.
Is there a better way to do it using enumerate or without using enumerate?

Comment: Your example says it should say "YES" for `[345,789,123,567,012345]`, but I doubt your code does that

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I think OP meant "YES" for `[3,4,5]`, `[7,8,9]` and so on.

Comment: yes, I meant [3,4,5], [7,8,9],etc . Ill edit it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `enumerate` in order to check the elements of your lists are continuous. You can simply achieve it via creating a function using [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) as:

```
def check_continuity(my_list):
    return all(a+1==b for a, b in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))
```

Same result can be achieved by [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as *(similar to [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) but with `not` and `!=` for comparision)*:

```
def check_continuity(my_list):
    return not any(a+1!=b for a, b in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))
```

Above functions will return `True`/`False` depending upon whether your list is continuous or not.

Sample run:

```
# Continuous Lists
>>> check_continuity([3, 4, 5])
True
>>> check_continuity([7, 8, 9])
True
>>> check_continuity([1, 2, 3])
True

# Non Continuous Lists
>>> check_continuity([9, 1, 0])
False
>>> check_continuity([3, 2, 4])
False
>>> check_continuity([5, 5])
False
```

In order to print "YES"/"NO", you may make a simple `if..else`check outside the function call as:

```
>>> "YES" if check_continuity([1, 2, 3]) else "NO"
'YES'

# OR update the return statement in your function to
#    return "NO" if any(a+1!=b for a, b in zip(my_list, my_list[1:])) else "YES"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need `enumerate` at all, given that you never use `e`. Try using the `for...else` block:

```
inp = [1, 2, 3]

for idx in range(len(inp) - 1):
    if inp[idx + 1] - inp[idx] != 1:
        print("NO")
        break
else:
    print("YES")
```

You can also `zip` the list with its copy shifted by one (but that, well, makes a copy):

```
for x, y in zip(inp, inp[1:]):
    if y - x != 1:
        print("NO")
        break
else:
    print("YES")
```

Or make this into a function:

```
def increasing_by_one(inp):
    for x, y in zip(inp, inp[1:]):
        if y - x != 1:
            return False
    return True

print('YES' if increasing_by_one(inp) else 'NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this line of code:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]

True if(list(range(min(l), max(l)+1)) == l) else False
```

In this sample, the output will be True.

Answer (score -1):

a1,a2,a3..an are continuous when (a1+a2+..+an)/n equals (a1+an)/2.
I don't know python but I am sure you can easily get first,last and count of a list.

update,

sorry, the original answer is a necessary condition, not a sufficient condition. so that's not right.

Comment: This is wrong. For example for `n=2` your condition would always be satisfied, but it clearly shouldn't for e.g. `[2, 4]`.